# How to convert a method from boolean to int (java)?

Tags: java, int, boolean, converters, 2d-games

so I have to build a Sudoku game in Java. I am able confirm in my method that the numbers 1 to 9 only appear once in each row/column. However, I have this set up as a boolean and can not for the life of me figure out how to convert this to an integer (so that I can return the row/column where the error occurs).

```
public static boolean rowColumnCheck(int[][] array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        boolean[] rowArray = new boolean[9];
        boolean[] columnArray = new boolean[9];
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            int currentNumberRow = array[i][j];
            int currentNumberColumn = array[j][i];
            if ((currentNumberRow < 1 || currentNumberRow > 9)
                    && (currentNumberColumn < 1 || currentNumberColumn > 9)) {
                return false;
            }
            rowArray[currentNumberRow - 1] = true;
            columnArray[currentNumberColumn - 1] = true;

        }
        for (boolean booleanValue : rowArray) {
            if (!booleanValue) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        for (boolean booleanValue : columnArray) {
            if (!booleanValue) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What value are you trying to return? When someone calls that method, what should they expect from it? Converting boolean to int doesn't seem logical; I mean, you could instead return `-1` or `1`, but at that point, you might as well just use boolean. What should it return and why? Usually people wanna change a `String` to an `int` for calculation purposes, but numbers can't be represented as a boolean like it can for a String (like mentioned above, only -1 and 1)

Comment: The reason I want it to return an integer is because I want the column/row where this error occurs. I figured I could just modify the return type to integer. Then, run the For loop and return the integer where the For loop does not successfully work, but I am not having any luck.

Comment: `currentNumberRow` and `currentNumberColumn` don't make sense to me. The way you're accessing the values in `array` seems pretty random; I'm not sure why `[i][j]` represents the value for row, and `[j][i]` represents the value for column. Also, returning an `int` will only allow you to return 1 value, so you won't be able to return which row AND column the error occured at; there are a few solutions around that. The for loop controls which row/column you're at. `j` and `i` are specifying the row and column, so i'm not sure why you need `currentNumberRow` and `currentNumberColumn`

Comment: If you aren't sure what I'm confused about: what do `currentNumberColumn` the other one represent? What is stored in `array`? If it's a part of the sudoki board, then `[i][j]` and `[j][i]` are accessing what seems to be random values

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Each method basically has just a return type and a boolean is not compatible with an Integer. What you could do is change the return type to Integer or to Pair if you need to return a set of coordinates and return null if is not there.

I guess it would be something like this. If null there was no error, and on the pair is the error location.

```
public static Pair rowColumnCheck(int[][] array) {

    Pair <Integer, Integer> p = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        boolean[] rowArray = new boolean[9];
        boolean[] columnArray = new boolean[9];
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            int currentNumberRow = array[i][j];
            int currentNumberColumn = array[j][i];
            if ((currentNumberRow < 1 || currentNumberRow > 9)
                    && (currentNumberColumn < 1 || currentNumberColumn > 9)) {
                p = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(i, j);
                return p;
            }
            rowArray[currentNumberRow - 1] = true;
            columnArray[currentNumberColumn - 1] = true;

        }
        // Not really sure why you are doing this?
        for (boolean booleanValue : rowArray) {
            if (!booleanValue) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        for (boolean booleanValue : columnArray) {
            if (!booleanValue) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: "*What you could do is change the return type to Integer*" - Thats what he's asking for help on

Comment: That's what I'm asking. How can I alter this method to do what you suggested? I attempted to change the return type to Integer but could not successfully modify the body to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you want sometimes to return a row/column pair, sometimes a row, and sometimes a column. If this is right, then you need to create an extra class:

```
public class RowCol {
    public final int row;
    public final int col;

    public RowCol(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }
}
```

Now when you want to identify the place where the error occurred, you can

```
return new RowCol(i,j);
```

or to indicate a row without specifying a column

```
return new RowCol(i,-1);
```

and similarly for a column

```
return new RowCol(-1,j);
```

The return type of your method will be `RowCol`, and when you get one back from your method, you'll be able to interrogate its `row` and `col` fields to find out the co-ordinates of the return value.